# gcloud sql export permission denied for table

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm using the cmd `gcloud sql export` to dump all my databases on storage. It was working well since months, on crontab.
Now i'm receiving this error `pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for table ...` for all the databases.
I've checked serviceaccounts permissions, there is no problem with that, i can create a new database and export it, i've checked my setup on an other instance and so on.

If i `grant select on all table in schema public to cloudsqlimportexport` it works again, so the issue seems to be that the user cloudsqlimportexport has loosing grant in all my database suddenly ? I don't understand how it can be possible and why i should grant it again in all my databases (i've many databases and many schemas !).

In the log i didn't see anything special (i can see exactly the day where it appends), no maintenance was done and i don't remember doing anything critical on my instance.

If i clone my instance one day before the last working export i still cannot export from this clone.

Are there an explanation of this ?

Comment: It looks like internal analysis required, feel free to contact [google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)

Comment: Yes, it was probably an internal issue, it was resolved few days after even if i didn't do anything. I just clicked on "send feedback" on the console UI. Surprise that i didn't receive any mail and no log was showing an operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was probably an internal issue, it was resolved few days after even if i didn't do anything. I just clicked on "send feedback" on the console UI

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem.
On 3/15 I suddenly started getting the error, but on 3/21 I was able to get it to work correctly in an environment where nothing had been changed.
Has there been any change in your environment?

From what I have verified, it seems to occur when the database owner is a user other than cloudsqladmin. I was getting an error with the export function on the console screen.
I was able to get it to work by using the grant command to make cloudsqlimportexport have the same privileges as the user who owns the database.